# Query to calculate beginning stock, stock in, stock out, stock balance in MYSQL by controling inflation(increase, rise, rising) of unity price

Tags: mysql, sql

Good morning,

I have a mysql database which contains three tables:

1. Product Table

[image]

2. stockin Table

[image]

3. stockout Table

[image]

And I have the below query which works well, and it helps me to generate the legder report on picture 4 below:

```
SELECT 
  Product.Product_Code,
  Product.Product_Color,
  Product.Product_Model,
  IFNull(QtyBeginningStockIn.Qty_In, 0)-IFNull(QtyBeginningStockOut.Qty_Out, 0) QtyBeginningStock,
  IFNull(UntyBeginningStockIn.Uprice_In, 0) UntyBeginningStock,
  IFNull(BeginningStockIn.Amount, 0)-IFNull(BeginningStockOut.Amount, 0) BeginningStock,
IFNull(QtyPeriodStockIn.Qty_In, 0) QtyStockIn,
IFNull(UntyPeriodStockIn.Uprice_In, 0) UntyStockIn,
IFNull(PeriodStockIn.Amount, 0) StockIn,
IFNull(QtyPeriodStockOut.Qty_Out, 0) QtyStockOut,
IFNull(UntyPeriodStockOut.Uprice_Out, 0) UntyStockOut,
IFNull(PeriodStockOut.Amount, 0) StockOut,
IFNull(QtyBeginningStockIn.Qty_In, 0)-IFNull(QtyBeginningStockOut.Qty_Out, 0)+IFNull(QtyPeriodStockIn.Qty_In, 0)-IFNull(QtyPeriodStockOut.Qty_Out, 0) QtyStockBalance,
IFNull(UntyclosingStockIn.Uprice_In, 0) UntyclosingStockIn,
IFNull(BeginningStockIn.Amount, 0)-IFNull(BeginningStockOut.Amount, 0)+IFNull(PeriodStockIn.Amount, 0)-IFNull(PeriodStockOut.Amount, 0) StockBalance
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Qty_In) Qty_In,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockIn
  WHERE StockIn_Date < '2012/01/02'
  group by Product_Code
) QtyBeginningStockIn ON QtyBeginningStockIn.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Qty_Out) Qty_Out,
    Product_Code
  FROM Stockout
  WHERE StockOut_Date < '2012/01/02'
  group by Product_Code
) QtyBeginningStockOut ON QtyBeginningStockOut.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    Uprice_In,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockIn
  WHERE StockIn_Date < '2012/01/02'
  group by Product_Code
) UntyBeginningStockIn ON UntyBeginningStockIn.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockIn
  WHERE StockIn_Date < '2012/01/02'
  group by Product_Code
) BeginningStockIn ON BeginningStockIn.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockOut
  WHERE StockOut_Date < '2012/01/02'
    group by Product_Code
) BeginningStockOut ON BeginningStockOut.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Qty_In) Qty_In,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockIn
  WHERE StockIn_Date >= '2012/01/02' AND StockIn_Date < '2012/01/31'
    group by Product_Code
) QtyPeriodStockIn ON QtyPeriodStockIn .Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    Uprice_In,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockIn
  WHERE StockIn_Date >= '2012/01/02' AND StockIn_Date < '2012/01/31'
    group by Product_Code
) UntyPeriodStockIn ON UntyPeriodStockIn .Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockIn
  WHERE StockIn_Date >= '2012/01/02' AND StockIn_Date < '2012/01/31'
    group by Product_Code
) PeriodStockIn ON PeriodStockIn .Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    SUM(Qty_Out) Qty_Out,
    Product_Code
  FROM Stockout
  WHERE StockOut_Date >= '2012/01/02' AND StockOut_Date < '2012/01/31'
    group by Product_Code
) QtyPeriodStockOut ON QtyPeriodStockOut .Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
     Uprice_Out,
    Product_Code
  FROM Stockout
  WHERE StockOut_Date >= '2012/01/02' AND StockOut_Date < '2012/01/31'
    group by Product_Code
) UntyPeriodStockOut ON UntyPeriodStockOut .Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
   SUM(Amount) Amount,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockOut
  WHERE StockOut_Date >= '2012/01/02' AND StockOut_Date < '2012/01/31'
    group by Product_Code
) PeriodStockOut ON PeriodStockOut.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    Uprice_In,
    Product_Code
  FROM StockIn
  WHERE StockIn_Date < '2012/01/02'
  group by Product_Code
) UntyclosingStockIn ON UntyclosingStockIn.Product_Code = Product.Product_Code
```

4. Ledger report

   [image]

And my question is, is it possible to generate a Ledger report which can display all transactions by details include transaction date, instead of summarize transaction like in my report? Which query can I use?. Thank you

Comment: Everything is possible

Comment: You need to provide an exact expected outcome and what you have tried to achive it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by union `stockin` and `stockout` tables. Also you can use negative and positive values for different types of transactions. For example:

```
(SELECT StockIn_date AS `Date`, Product_code, Qty_In AS Qty, Uprice_In AS Uprice, Qty_In*Uprice_In AS Amount, 'StockIn' AS `Type`
FROM stockin)
UNION ALL
(SELECT StockOut_date AS `Date`, Product_code, -Qty_Out AS Qty, Uprice_Out AS Uprice, -Qty_Out*Uprice_Out AS Amount, 'StockOut' AS `Type`
FROM stockout)
ORDER BY `Date`;
```